# Создание поля с множественным выбором в таблице в Django

Tags: python, django

Новичок в Django, не судите строго.

Хочу сделать простейший сайт с тестом. Для этого нужны две таблицы: Question и Choices. Причём каждому вопросу соответствуют однозначно свои 4 варианта ответа, только один из которых - правильный.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)

# вариант ответа
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = ForeginKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # а вот здесь не знаю, как создать такой член класса, чтобы он 
    # одновременно содержал 4 варианта ответа и удобно хранился в таблице
```

Версия Django - 2.1

Comment: Обычный `CharField`. Вариант ответа должен содержать **один** вариант ответа.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, так ведь один `CharField` хранит только один вариант ответа, а мне нужно, чтобы было 4 варианта. Или я чего не понимаю?

Comment: Не понимаете. Каждый экземпляр `Answer` должен хранить один ответ. Нужно 4 ответа - создаёте четыре экземпляра.

Comment: Это подробно и в то же время просто описано во 2-й главе [руководства Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я как раз эту главу и хотел бы реализовать, но сделать инициализацию не из `shell`, а программным путём.

Comment: Никакой принципиальной разницы нет откуда выполняться коду - из консоли или из представления.

Answer (score 1):

Можно считать один экземпляр класса Answer как один вариант ответа. Вы можете создать несколько вариантов ответа и связать каждый из них внешним ключом с экземпляром класса Question.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = ForeginKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # True, если ответ верный
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ  А не могли бы пояснить, как грамотнее всего загрузить эти варианты ответа в таблицу БД и считать для каждого объекта `Answer` свой вариант ответа?

Comment: "считать для каждого объекта Answer свой вариант ответа?" - каждый объект Answer это один вариант ответа и он может быть правильным или нет. Каждый вопрос будет иметь несколько таких прикрепленных к нему объектов.

Comment: У вас эти варианты ответов где-то хранятся готовые?

Comment: в текстовом файле если только.

Comment: Создаете модели, делаете миграции. Далее я бы сделал кастомную команду как описано здесь https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/ . То есть запускаете команду с помощью `manage.py load_answers`, например. И она уже будет считывать данные из файла и создавать записи в БД.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Сейчас попробую.